# CSS display:flex align-items:baseline not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I am having trouble creating a consistent flexbox between Chrome, Safari and Firefox.  The css I have works great in Chrome/Safari but fails for Firefox.  The issue is when I try to have a      container element defined as:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

my children elements align properly in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox they are aligned at the bottom and don't seems to have much bearing on the location of the text.

**UPDATE**

Ok so having investigated further, I believe the issue is that firefox vs. chrome and safari have a different way of calculating the baseline.  I essentially gave up on firefox and created conditional css which will `align-items:flex-start` when using firefox and otherwise use baseline.

Comment: I don't see any difference: http://jsfiddle.net/b8qr2uub/

Comment: I have tried to reproduce on jsfiddle but with no luck.  I had a link up before to my website but if you checkout [link]http://nomadto.com with firefox and then change the css to align-items: baseline; on .searchEntryArea you will see the toolbar gets messed up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here is my article](http://kizu.ru/en/blog/flex-baseline/) about aligning blocks to their baselines. The [example for align-items](http://kizu.ru/en/blog/flex-baseline/#another-way) works ok in Fx except for the bug with overflowed block and paddings, which could be fixed in the same way it is fixed a while later.

However, for your example at http://www.nomadto.com/ things are different: the problem is that when you're doing `align-items: baseline`, Fx expects to see only inline-content inside, so if you'd replace most nested `display: flex` with `display: inline-flex` there, things would be much better. However, as there are **a lot** of extra wrappers and styles, it is rather hard right now to write you a full patch for fixing stuff, but if you'd create a more simple example somewhere at codepen or jsbin, I could try to fix it to work properly with proper baseline alignment.

Comment: Thanks great answer and good article, I think I have a better understanding of baseline now.

Comment: Very helpful. Since the treatment of this is different between Chrome and FF, do you know which one is compliant with the spec? (That is, if the spec even prescribes a behavior for what happens when block elements are inside a flex parent with align-items: baseline.)